# Why Google Maintenance broke PostreSQL in project 763485212249?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

yesterday on our `tahmeel-postgresql-prod` instance there was a maintenance update https://dzwonsemrish7.cloudfront.net/items/0t253L361v411g060n26/Image%202018-10-09%20at%201.46.38%20PM.png

Thanks to that update, we started to see errors `ERROR:  could not access file "$libdir/postgis-2.3": No such file or directory` when we tried to use postgis https://dzwonsemrish7.cloudfront.net/items/2G371k0D2j1K1J2x3q0P/Image%202018-10-09%20at%201.48.04%20PM.png

Here you can see logs from the database, problems started to arise when the maintenance started https://dzwonsemrish7.cloudfront.net/items/2g3a28171l1v3R2H2838/Image%202018-10-09%20at%201.53.09%20PM.png

so what we did was to clone the db as `tahmeel-postgresql-prod-clone` and switch the app to use new db.

My question is -- what happened and why?

Comment: Since this is not a programming question, this issue should be posted either in [Google's Issue Tracker](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker) or on [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com).

Comment: I'm voting to close this as Off-Topic, as it has nothing to do with programming. Your best shot would be contacting GCP Support

Comment: Try in the [Open Cloud SQL issues](https://issuetracker.google.com/savedsearches/559773)